# C# structure passing to unmanaged dll function

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I have the C/C++ written dll whith next function:

__declspec( dllexport) short CiBoardInfo(canboard_t * binfo);

And structure declared:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char brdnum;
    unsigned long hwver;
    short chip[4];
    char name[64];
    char manufact[64];
} canboard_t;
```

I need to use it in C#, so i try this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct canboard_t{
        public Byte brdnum;
        public UInt32 hwver;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
        public Int16 chip;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
        public String name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
        public String manufact;
    };

   class Chai
    {
        [DllImport("chai.dll")]
        public static extern Int16 CiInit();
        [DllImport("chai.dll")]
        public static extern Int16  CiBoardInfo(ref canboard_t binfo);
    }
```

and try to use it like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    canboard_t brd = new canboard_t();
    Chai.CiInit();
    Chai.CiBoardInfo(ref brd);
    this.Text = brd.manufact + " " + brd.name;
}
```

And it hangs when calling Chai.CiBoardInfo(ref brd)  with

> System.TypeLoadException.TypeLoadException

So what's wrong? As i understand i have incorrect written struct in my C# code. But i can not find where the mistake is.

```
 1. ChaiVGSNAG2.exe!ChaiVGSNAG2.Program.Main() Line 18 + 0x1d bytes  
 2. [from machine code to managed]  
 3. [from managed code to machine]  
 4. mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile,
    System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) +
    0x6b bytes  
 5. Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
    + 0x27 bytes  
 6. mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object
    state) + 0x6f bytes  
 7. mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
    executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
    state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes  
  8. mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
    executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
    state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes  
  9. mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
    executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
    state) + 0x41 bytes  
 10. mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44
    bytes  
 11. [from machine code to managed]
```

Comment: Code looks ok. Please, add some more StackTrace information.

Comment: I did not understand how to made it looks fine  in comments. So add it to the end of main topic.

Comment: Did you check if chai.dll is in your debug directory along the other dll's?

Comment: You are trying to turn Int16 into an array, no can do.  It must be `public Int16[] chip;` Note the added square brackets.

Comment: Oh, yes. Confirmed. It is really so. Thanks all. And especialy Hans Passant.